# Composer autoload custom classes

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I try to autoload my custom pdo class with composer.
Ran the following command to update autoload:

```
compser update
composer install
```

Both seem to work, no error prompted. **But**,

```
vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
```

Does not list the custom namespace added to composer.js.

**File structure**

```
-Root
 ->classes
   ->pdo
     ->class.php
 ->vendor
   ->various extensions loaded with composer
index.php
```

**PHP Class**

```
namespace Classes\Pdo;

Class DB {
    //Do some stuff...
}
```

**Composer.js**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Classes\\Pdo\\": "classes/pdo"
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
$pdo = new \Classes\Pdo\DB(); //Fatal error: Class 'Classes\Pdo\DB' not found
```

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: That just solved it, thanks!

Comment: No idea what `composer dump-autoload` does, but your question *was* the answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I just ran across this myself.

For future Googlers, in my case the issue turned out to be the name of the class file did not exactly match the class name.

See this post: [Why does 'composer dumpautoload -o' fix 'Class not found' PHP error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626122/why-does-composer-dumpautoload-o-fix-class-not-found-php-error)