# Why does 'composer dumpautoload -o' fix 'Class not found' PHP error?

Tags: php, laravel-5, dependencies, composer-php, autoload

I have a Laravel `5.8` project that is dependent on a private package.

When I run `composer install` the package is installed and shows up in the vendor folder.

#### project composer.json

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "company/api-request": ">=1.0.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

#### package src/ApiRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace Company;

class APIRequest
{
    ...
}
```

#### package composer.json

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\": "src/"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

When I call the package

```
\Company\APIRequest::run();
```

I am getting

```
Message: Class 'Company\APIRequest' not found
```

I know the PHP syntax is correct because when I run `composer dumpautoload -o` the error is gone, but why is it necessary?

I expect `composer install` or `composer update` should be sufficient; I have no problem with external packages.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: As you can see with your external dependencies, this **should** work. But it doesn't, and it's very hard to guess what's wrong with the provided information. I guess a key detail must have been left out in your effort to produce a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class name and file name don't match, that would cause the auto-loading to not work since that is a requirement with PSR-4. From the [docs](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/):

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

If that's the case, `composer dumpautoload -o` is probably working around this for you, see [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/2zx3in/l5_composer_dumpautoload_gives_class_not_found/cpp5cxf?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

> The reason -o works, is Composer creates a giant associative array where classname = filename